# How to calculate 'half' of an affine transformation matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-cvst, affinetransform

I am looking to find 'half' of an affine transformation matrix using MATLAB. Yes I understand, 'half' a matrix isn't really correct, but exactly what I'm looking for was actually explained very well here: [stackexchange mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611359/affine-transformation-matrix-coefficients)

So I'm looking for an affine transformation matrix (B) which when applied twice to my image, will give the same result as when applying my initial matrix (A) once.

Reflection will not be part of A, otherwise it would be impossible to find B.

My initial matrix (A) is calculated using `A = estimateGeometricTransform(movingPoints,fixedPoints,'affine')`, which gives me an affine2d object.

If there is no way to find the 'half' matrix from the initial matrix, maybe the arrays of matched points can be manipulated in a way to find B from them.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a possibility to find the *half* matrix that you speak of. It is called the matrix square root. Suppose you have the matrixa `A`. In Matlab you can just do `B=sqrtm(A)`, where the `m` stands for matrix. Then you get a matrix `B`, where `norm(B*B - A)` is very small, if the matrix `A` was well behaved.

If I understand correctly you want to have *half* of an affine transformation `aff = @(x) A*x + b`. This can be done using homogenious coordinates. Every transformation `aff` can be represented by a the matrix
`M = [A b; zeros(1,length(b)) 1]`, where

```
normalize = @(y) y(1:end-1)/y(end);
affhom = @(x) normalize(M*[x; 1]);
```

Note that `aff` and `affhom` do exactly the same thing. Here we can use what I was talking about earlier. *Half* of `affhom` can be represented using

```
affhomhalf = @(x) normalize(sqrtm(M)*[x; 1])
```

where

```
affhomhalf(affhomhalf(y)) - aff(y)
```

is small for all `y`, if `A` and `b` were well behaved.

I'm not sure about this, but I think you can even decompose `sqrtm(M)` into an linear and translatory part.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will see if I can implement it and how well it works.